# Dynamically include data from contract in ERC721 JSON data

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment, erc-721

Let's say an ERC721 NFT contract includes a mapping:

`mapping(uint256 => uint16) public nftAttributeA; // uint256 is tokenId, uint16 is an attribute of the tokenId`

where the `nftAttribute` is updated for each NFT that is minted within the contract. As different functions on the contract are called, the `uint16` value for a given tokenId may change

Each NFT has as associated JSON file:

```
{"image": "https://example.com/1.png", "name": "object #1", "attributes": [ {"trait_type": "furry", "value": "true"}, {"trait_type": "fuzzy", "value": "false"}]}
```

Is there a way to dynamically include the current `nftAttribute` for a given NFT in the JSON (So it would show up on Opensea, etc)? So an NFT with an `nftAttributeA` value of `16` would have JSON data that'd be:

```
{"image": "https://example.com/1.png", "name": "object #1", "attributes": [ {"trait_type": "furry", "value": "true"}, {"trait_type": "fuzzy", "value": "false"},
{"trait_type": "nftAttributeA", "value": "16"}]}
```

The only thing I can think of is to hard code the ERC721 tokenIds' attributes and just include the `nftAttributeA` data, by doing a bunch of `string.concat` which is prepended with `data:application/json;utf8,` But maybe there is an easier way?